# bash variable filename with underscore unrecognized?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that will symlink all of my dotfiles related to bash into the home directory. I want the script to check if the filenames already exists, so that I I can rename/move them.

For some reason can't get my `if` test-command to recognize filenames that have an underscore in them.

When testing for files that already exist, this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in bashrc bash_profile bash_aliases
do
  filename=$HOME"/."$name

  if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
    echo "${filename} exists"
  else
    echo "${filename} doesn't exist"
  fi
done
```

Outputs:

```
/home/xavier/.bashrc exists
/home/xavier/.bash_profile doesn't exist
/home/xavier/.bash_aliases doesn't exist
```

What is it about the underscore that is causing this behavior, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Its working for me. Did you check that you have those files?

Comment: put `$HOME`  variable inside `"/."` so it should be like this `"$HOME/."` it should work correctly now .

Comment: Note that `-e` will fail if the file exists, but is a broken symlink

Comment: @authprivate the quoting, while weird, would not cause this issue.  shell guarantees correct expansion in this scenario.

Comment: @Ritesh I double checked the spelling, and the files are definitely there. @authprivate I tried your change, but I am still getting the same output. Right now those files are regular files, so I switched the operator to `-f`, but got the same result. Maybe this is an issue with my environment, and not the script?

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x` and post result please.

Comment: @thatotherguy, broken symlink was the issue. Thank you very much! Would you like to post that as a an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct as posted and underscore is not a problematic character in general.

You mention that you're symlinking the files -- if you're sure the files are there, verify that they are not broken symlinks. `-e file` will be false if the final target of the link doesn't exist.

Other things that can cause this are:

- lacking permissions
- invisible unicode characters like a zero-width space
- similar-looking unicode characters like `bаsh＿profile` which has a fullwidth low line instead of an underscore.
- running the script in a chroot or sandbox
- checking that the file exists in a different terminal than the one used for running the script -- it could be chrooted, SSH'd to another machine or started before a directory was mounted over the dir, and therefore have a different view of the fs

Comment: Thanks again for notifying me of this eccentricity with `-e`.  It makes sense now that I think about it. I ended up using  `ln --symbolic --force` so that broken symlinks are overwritten.